# Slow upload speed over ftp/sftp

Tags: ftp, sftp

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 machine and a Windows 10 machine both on the same local network (both connected via ethernet to the same router). I initially used SFTP to transfer files from the Windows machine to the Ubuntu machine, but the transfer speed was slow (10 simultaneous uploads at about 1 Mb/s).

I googled around and saw something about SFTP being slower than FTP so I set up vsftpd on the Ubuntu machine to allow for FTP connections. I then tried transferring files again, but the speeds are the same. I'm using Filezilla as the client on the Windows machine, and I checked that there were no speed limits set, and there doesn't seem to be any firewall issues (if there were, no data transfer would happen at all right?). I figured that over local network/same router file transfers should be 1 Gb/s (so 100 Mb/s for each of the 10 connections), as I have a fairly recent Verizon Fios router. Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: Here's the output of the requested commands from the comments:

```
➜  ~ sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
```

and

```
➜  ~ sudo ethtool -i eth0
driver: r8169
version:
firmware-version: rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

Also I forgot to mention this before, but my network looks like this (excluding other devices):

```
Main Router (Verizon FiOS-G1100)
|-- Ubuntu Machine (FTP Server)
|-- Router used as switch (Netgear WNDR4000)
    |-- Windows Machine (FTP Client)
```

Both routers support gigabit ethernet, and all my ethernet cables are CAT6, so I'm not sure where bottleneck is.

Comment: Would you add output of: `sudo ethtool <interface>` and `sudo ethtool  -i <interface>` Also I are you sure about unit Mbps (not MBps)

Comment: I believe so, as in Filezilla it uses MiB/s. It ended up getting faster, now it does 10 simulatenous uploads at anywhere from 3 - 12 MiB/s, but still a far cry from gigabit. I'll update the main post with the output of those commands you mentioned. Are there equivalent commands on the windows machine (ftp client) that I should run?